# Process all HTTP exceptions with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, exception, http-status-code-404

I have wasted a day already and still do not quite understand how can I process ALL HTTP exceptions with my ASP.NET logging method and `Server.Transfer` to my custom error page then?!

What I have tried:

1. `<customErrors redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"><error statusCode="404" redirect="Error.aspx?404" />`. Works only for `.aspx` files. Not works for non-aspx 404th. Can't `Server.Transfer` to dynamically generated URL. Strangelly not works with asHx handler, works with asPx pages.
2. `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" ><error statusCode="404" path="Error.aspx?404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />`. Didn't understand how it works. Shows white screen instead of my file when `responseMode="ExecuteURL"` is set. `responseMode="Redirect"` works okay, but I do not like the redirect. Can't `Server.Transfer` to dynamically generated URL.
3. Custom `IHttpModule` with `preCondition=""` and `context.Error += new EventHandler(OnError);`. For 500th it works pretty well, but unfortunately, for 404th works only for aspx files. `www.website.com/1234.aspx` - works okay. `www.website.com/2345` - not works.

So... how is it possible to handle all HTTP exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

options1&2 are only going to apply to requests handled by asp.net. You need to change the wildcard script mapping to asp.net. http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline

for #3 you need to use the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests on the modules section of the web.config. explained at the end of the same module

UPDATE:

This worked for me. I hope it's closer to what you want.

web.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="StaticFile"/>
            <add name="StaticFile"  type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Handle error with Global.asax

```cs
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext currentContext = application.Context;
        Exception currentException = application.Server.GetLastError();
        Debug.WriteLine("Application_Error " + currentContext.Request.PhysicalPath);
        application.Server.Transfer("~/CustomErrorTransfer.aspx");
    }
}
```

Or in an HttpModule

```cs
public class ErrorHandlerModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += ContextOnError;
    }

    private static void ContextOnError(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext currentContext = application.Context;
        Debug.WriteLine("ErrorHandlerModule " + currentContext.Request.PhysicalPath);
        Exception currentException = application.Server.GetLastError();
        application.Server.ClearError();
        application.Server.Transfer("~/CustomErrorTransfer.aspx");
    }
}
```

with this added to the web.config

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <add name="Errors" type="MyRootNamespace.ErrorHandlerModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

CustomErrorTransfer.aspx used by other pages

```xml
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head runat="server"><title></title></head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Custom Error Page</h1>
        Current Path: <%= Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath  %><br/>
        Original Path: <%=  Request.PhysicalPath %><br/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, before I asked my question, I tried both `preCondition=""` and `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in #3. It does not work for non-aspx 404th. It hits `BeginRequest` event, it hits `EndRequest` event, but it does not hit `Error` event. For aspx 404th and 500th it works great. Is there a workaround?!